# Why is pandas eval not working anymore with where?

Tags: python, pandas, function, where-clause, eval

I was using pandas eval within a where that sits inside a function in order to create a column in a data frame. While it was working in the past, not it doesn't. There was a recent move to Python 3 within our dataiku software. Could that be the reason for it?

Below will be the code that is now in place

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from numpy import where, nan

d = {'ASSET': ['X','X','A','X','B'], 'PRODUCT': ['Z','Y','Z','C','Y']}
MAIN_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def val_per(ASSET, PRODUCT):
    return(
            where(pd.eval("ASSET== 'X' & PRODUCT == 'Z'"),0.04,
                  where(pd.eval("PRODUCT == 'Y'"),0.08,1.5)
                 )
           )

MAIN_2_df = (MAIN_df.eval("PCT = @val_per(ASSET, PRODUCT)"))
```

The error received now is <class 'TypeError'>: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: WElcome to SO! Please share a minimal reproducible set of your data, otherwise, it might be difficult to know where the error comes from.

Comment: Have you tried to simply use ```np.where``` instead of importing where from numpy?

Comment: Hi @SergedeGossondeVarennes ! Added some sample structure of the dataframe

Comment: I tried now np.where after restarting the kernel and not importing it anymore, but it throws the same error

Comment: Why are you using eval? just change the last line with MAIN_df['PCT'] = val_per(MAIN_df.ASSET, MAIN_df.PRODUCT) (u can make a copy of MAIN_df first and append the column PCT to the df copy.

Comment: Hi @NachoR. ! It does indeed work with the proposed approach. It's still a mystery to me why it's not working anymore after the move to Python 3

It was useful to use eval in the situation where I would have more functions that I wanted to use in one go and I could string them along with . in between them

Comment: Your code works for me. Check versions of pandas and numpy.

Comment: Try upgrading numpy to 1.23.1 and pandas to 1.5.2

Comment: Unfortunately the package upgrade is not under my control and I will have to contact the administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the last two lines with:

```
MAIN_2_df = MAIN_df.copy()

MAIN_2_df =  val_per(MAIN_2_df.ASSET, MAIN_2_df.PRODUCT)
```

This approach will work faster for large dataframes. You can use a vectorized aproach to faster results.